# Do i need a [ Craft PRO ] to create accounts/User management for my LMS website?

Tags: craft3, login, user-profile, frontend-form

I'm still a new to Craft and trying to make an LMS website

when i started to search about the [ Sign up/Sign in ] i read that the official docs :

**https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/front-end-user-accounts**

requires a **Craft PRO** to achieve this steps ( users can register a new account / login to their profile)

so how can i do this with or without Pro version of Craft?

any help (ideas, articles, links, snippets...) would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: What is an “LMS website”?

Comment: LMS : Learning Management System ( it's like Udemy, Coursera … )
a website provides online video courses and each user (student) has his own account to monitor his progress and achievement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want multiple [user accounts](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/users.html) in Craft, then you'd need Craft Pro, regardless of the type of site you're trying to building on the front-end.

Comment: Thank you @Brad for your answer. So now i would go for the **Pro free trail** meanwhile (Dev) and when it come to production i'll purchase the Pro plan.